# How to inject actions via @Composable lambda like f.e. TopAppBar

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I tried

```kotlin
@Composable
fun foo(actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit) {
    Row {
        IconButton(onClick = {...}) { Icon(...) }

        actions()
    }
}

@Composable
fun bar() {
    foo(actions = {
        IconButton(onClick = { }) {
            Icon(
                painterResource(R.drawable.ic),
                null,
            )
        }
    })
}
```

But so the tint of the icon defined in the lambda argument doesn't match the other defined directly in `foo`. In dark mode it's black with bad constrast so probably not intended. Also, it seems to be larger.

On the other hand, I already have some sort of "layout" composables which take a lambda and there everything works. So if noone can reproduce I have to look over it again. But maybe there is something apparent I do wrong?